# Unknown Safe Contract Connected To My MM Wallet

Tags: safe-core

I was making a new Safe account but found an unrecognized Safe account tied to my account. The Safe Account's address is:

`matic:0x68d231A531BcF34199a825AE568aa79b695f7965`

My metamask address is `0x1aa5aBfD850012297428b509fB84FCD9F9f995cB` and it is designated as a signer and master copy.

I have no recollection of making this safe account, and do not recognize the txs the safe account is executing.

My questions are:

How is someone interacting with this safe despite the fact that I am  the only signer? Is there any kind of security risk for my future accounts? Why would someone make me a signer/master copy? Why did they use my account for this? Can I touch the funds shown on the safe website? How would I do that?

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

The MM account you shared is indeed an owner of that Safe. After some research, we found that this Safe could be related to Polymarket. Maybe you have already used Polymarket, which may use a modified version of the Safe smart contract to control funds. Checking your pending funds in Polymarket, using your MM for login, might give you some further intel.

We discourage the usage of this Safe as a personal Safe and recommend that you create a new one to use as your wallet.